# Unable to compare two char arrays against each other

Tags: c

I have a reverse function that I would like to use to compare two strings against each other, but it doesn't seem to work. I think that every time the string is iterated over it overwrites the value every time. I'm think that it needs to be stored in a separate array to be able to evaluate the two against each other. Here's what I have so far:

```
int compare_strings(char [], char []);

char* reverse(char* str)
{
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    i=j=temp=0;

    j=strlen(str)-1;
    for (i=0; i<j; i++, j--)
    {
        temp=str[i];
        str[i]=str[j];
        str[j]=temp;
    }
    return str;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {
    char word[100];
    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName,"r");
    char s[100];
    char formattedWord[100];
    while(fgets(word, 100, file)!=NULL){
        memset(s,'\0',sizeof s);
        char *token=strtok(word," ");
        while(token!=NULL){
            size_t n=strlen(s);
            sprintf(&s[n],"%s",token);
            token=strtok(NULL," ");

        }
        if (reverse(s) == s)
            {
                printf("%s\n", reverse(s));
            }    
        }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are comparing pointers but not the values. Use `strcmp`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: Why your Title say CHARS and you need to compare an Array of chars (string) ?  **if(strcmp(string1,string2) == 0){printf("True");}else{printf("Flase");}** [Try this](http://ideone.com/yDRhCl)

Comment: "Evaluate two strings against each other"? What is that supposed to mean? "Evaluate" does not mean "compare".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems.  First is this:

```
if (reverse(s) == s)
```

This is not how you compare two strings.  You instead call `strcmp`, and if it returns 0 the two strings are the same.

However, the `reverse` function reverses the string in place.  So with either method the result will always be true.

Inside of `reverse`, you want to allocate new memory and write the reversed string there, then return that new string.

```
char* reverse(char* str)
{
    int i, j;
    char *temp;
    i=j=0;

    temp = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    j=strlen(str)-1;
    for (i=0; j>=0; i++, j--)
    {
        temp[j]=str[i];
    }
    temp[strlen(str)] = '\0';
    return temp;
}
```

Now when you call `reverse`, you need to save off the return value so you can `free` that memory later.

```
    char *s2;
    ...
    s2 = reverse(s);
    if (!strcmp(s,s2))
        {
            printf("%s\n", s2);
        }
    free(s2);
```

Finally, `fgets` will append a newline to the end of the string to read if there's enough space for it.  So you need to account for that when tokenizing the string:

```
    char *token=strtok(word," \n");
    while(token!=NULL){
        size_t n=strlen(s);
        sprintf(&s[n],"%s",token);
        token=strtok(NULL," \n");
    }
```

Comment: Ah, my reversed string keeps coming out as (null)

Comment: I'm using a text file as a command line argument. The file reads like so: happy b00b face monster cake

Comment: so it should come out as happy yppah b00b b00b face ecaf monster retsnom cake ekac

Comment: @Fullmetal_Alchemist_Fan Looks good with my changes.  Please update your question with your updated code (after the original code) and the input file.

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot. I forgot to assign s2 to reverse(s). It works now! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

You can't do `if (reverse(s) == s)` because that will simply compare the pointer values. You must use a library function such as `strcmp` or to iterate through each char and compare them.

Something like this would be valid.

```
char *reverse_s = reverse(s);
if(!strcmp(reverse_s, s)) {
  printf("%s\n", reverse_s);
}
```